# Confusion regarding the formula to determine the length of Earth's shadow in space.

Tags: geometry

In a book I'm reading, [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLwkk.jpg) is used to represent the geomoetry behind determining the length of Earth's shadow in space given that its center is a length S from that of the Sun. In this book, it is stated that if the line PO represents 'd', then l=rd/R, which makes perfect sense; however, since d=l+s, and we don't know l, the author goes on to state that because d=l+s, "it follows" that l=(rs)/(R-r). Unfortunately, they give no explanation as to why it follows, leaving me confused as to why this should be an easy conclusion to come to. It seems like a little too specific of a question to Google, and copying the diagram down on paper and adding to/doing math on it hasn't yielded an answer to my question either.

Hints that might make it easier to come to an answer on my own terms are appreciated above all else, but all help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using similar triangles, we have that
\begin{align*}
 \frac{l}{r} &= \frac{l+s}{R} \\
 \implies \frac{l}{r} - \frac{l}{R} &= \frac{s}{r} \\
 \implies l \left(\frac{1}{r}- \frac{1}{R}\right)= \frac{s}{r} \\
 \implies l &= \frac{s}{r} \left(\frac{1}{r}- \frac{1}{R}\right)^{-1} \\
   &= \frac{s}{r} \cdot \left( \frac{R-r}{rR} \right)^{-1}      \\
   &= \frac{s}{r} \cdot \frac{rR}{R-r} \\
   &= \frac{s R}{R-r}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sense now. I think you may have forgotten to put a '-1' where it would go in the exponent space for ((R-r)/(rR)), since that would make it ((rR)/(R-r)) in the next step. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Thanks, and you're right. Should be fixed now.